# Integers divide several solutions to Greatest Common Divisor equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm not sure about the topic's correctness but my problem is following:

Suppose $u_1,v_1$ and $u_2,v_2$ are two different solutions for $au_i + bv_i = 1$, then $a \mid v_2-v_1$ and $b\mid u_1-u_2$.

Well, I have tried to prove this without success, but here are some of my thoughts so far. I want to show that $(v_2-v_1)=ak$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, and I also know that $au_1+bv_1 = au_2+bv_2 \implies a(u_1-u_2) = b(v_2-v_1)$. In this last equality I know that $gcd(a,b)=1$ from the initial assumption, but what can I say about $gcd((v_2-v_1),(u_1-u_2))$ ? Does that help me in any way?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

If $u_1,v_1$ and $u_2,v_2$ are solutions to $au_i+bv_i=1$, then $$0=au_1+bv_1-au_2-bv_2=a(u_1-u_2)+b(v_1-v_2).$$
Thus $a \mid b(v_1-v_2)$. Now use $(a,b)=1$ to conclude $a \mid (v_1-v_2)$.

Comment: How do you conclude that $a \mid b(v_1-v_2)$ from that equation? Also, a should divide $v_2-v_1$ not $v_1-v_2$ unless it divides both?

Comment: @Math83 The equation is equivalent to $a(u_2-u_1)=b(v_1-v_2)$, hence the right side is divided by $a$. Now if $a\mid (v_1-v_2)$ then also $a \mid (v_2-v_1)$ because they differ by a factor of $-1$. If you don't like the sign anyway, you can multiply the first equation by $-1$.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not yet convinced: why can you divide the right hand side with $a$? How do you know that $b(v_1-v_2)$ is divisible by $a$?

Comment: Well, tell us what makes you hesitate, then :). Let me try it again: We have $a(u_1-u_2) = b(v_2-v_1)$. Now as $a$ and $b$ have no common divisor, all prime factors of $a$ must appear in $(v_2-v_1)$, meaning that $a \mid (v_2-v_1)$.

Comment: Wow! I think I got it, thanks! Just to verify: in general case if $am=bn$ and $gcd(a,b)=1$ then $a=p_{a1}..p_{ak}$ and $b=p_{b1}..p_{bl}$ where each prime $p_{ai} \neq p_{bj}$ for all $i,j$, we have that $p_{a1}..p_{ak}m = p_{b1}..p_{bl}n$ and because all the primes were not equal, $m=p_{b1}..p_{bl}$ and $n=p_{a1}..p_{ak}$. Therefore we can divide either $a$ on right-hand side or $b$ on left-hand side. Maybe this was trivial, but I just could not see that, thanks again!

Comment: @Math83 You are welcome ;) You are right with the above comment except for a slight detail: As we don't know that $(n,m)=1$, there may be another factor $g$ that divides both $m$ and $n$, that is $m=gp_{b1}\dots p_{bl}$, $n=gp_{a1}\dots gp_{ak}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$au_i+bv_i=1$$

can be rewritten as

$$au_i = 1-bv_i$$

so you have the two equations 
$$au_1 = 1-bv_1$$
$$au_2 = 1-bv_2$$

from which follows that

$$a(u_1-u_2)=b(v_2-v_1)$$

You already know that $\gcd(a,b)=1$, you can use the equation above to deduce the divisibility you need.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but all that I already stated in my initial question. What is desired is to know how you deduce from $a(u_1-u_2) = b(v_2-v_1)$ the divisors asked for. Or more explicitly, if $(v_2-v_1)=ak$ what is k? I suspect you divide $a(u_1-u_2)/b$ but how do you prove that it is valid?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ \ \color{#0a0}a\mid \color{#c00}{b(v_2-v_1\!)}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}a\mid \overbrace{(\color{#0a0}a\,u_1+v_1\color{#c00}b)}^{\large =\ 1}(\color{#c00}{v_2-v_1}\!).\ \, $  Alternatively use Euclid's Lemma.

**Remark** $\ $ This shows that $\ a\mid b\color{}c\,\Rightarrow\,a\mid\gcd(a,b)\color{}c.\,$ Yours is special case $\,\gcd(a,b)=1$.

This will be clarified *arithmetically* when your learn modular arithmetic, where it can be rewritten as follows. If $\,\gcd(a,b)=1\,$ then $\,b^{-1}$ exists $\,$ mod $a\,$ so mutiplying $\,bc\equiv 0\,$ by $\,b^{-1}$ yields $\,c\equiv 0,\,$ i.e. $\,b\,$ is invertible so cancelllable. Above the Bezout identity yields the inverse, i.e. by Bezout $\,\gcd(a,b)=1$ $\,\Rightarrow\,$ $\, au_1\!+ v_1 b = 1,\,$ so, $\,$ mod $\,a\!:\ v_1b\equiv 1$ $\,\Rightarrow\,$  $b^{-1}\equiv v_1$.